# Artikel beim Vorhandensein des nachgestellten Genitivs immer notwendig?

Tags: article, grammaticality, genitive

Let's assume you write an e-mail to a bike seller and issue a question:

> Sehr geehrter Herr Müller,
>
> ich bin der Käufer des Fahrrades Nr. 123.  Ich hätte folgende Frage an Sie: [...]

You are the only buyer, but you want to leave it unspecified whether the buyer is unique or whether a community of a few people has bought the bike.  How to do it?  Do you need an article before "Käufer" or can you leave it out?

Answer (score 2):

You can omit the Article in

> Ich bin Käufer des Fahrrades Nr. 123...

and you can, in your specific case, use a *definite* article as in

> Ich bin der Käufer des Fahrrades ...

Not using an article at all is normally used in standing expressions or when you cannot decide whether to use a definite or indefinite Article like in

> Käufer des Fahrrades vom Typ xyz wenden sich bitte an die Reklamationsabteilung

(we are not sure wether we sold none, one, or many, but anyone who has bought one should contact complaints)

In your case, it is very clear you bought the bike on your own and alone, so you would normally use a definite article.

Or even better

> Ich habe am xx.xx.xxxx das Fahrrad Nr. 123 bei Ihnen gekauft und hätte folgende Frage ...

Comment: @LeonMeier No, I think it’s good the way it is. Because the single buyer will likely only have bought one bike.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not always necessary. While in your example it makes sense, you wouldn't use it with

> Ich bin Eigentümer eines nagelneuen Sportwagens.

Comment: You could use an article here without doing anything wrong.

Comment: You can't use `der` because there are more car owners. You wouldn't use `ein` either because it sounds awkward (at least to me).

Comment: Can't see a reason why not to use *der* - works perfectly for me. There is no difference between "der Käufer des Fahrrades" and "der Eigentümer eines Sportwagens". Agree that *ein* sounds funny as it somehow implies the car has more than one owner (which is not completely impossible).

Comment: "Der Eigentümer eines Sportwagens" implies there's only one - perfectly possible with "des Sportwagens" but not with an indefinite one. "Ein Eigentümer des Sportwagens" would be one of many owners of a specific car.

Comment: "'Ein Eigentümer des Sportwagens' would be one of many owners of a specific car." and this is an absolutely correct german sentence. you could also say "Ich bin ein Eigentümer eines Mehrfamilienhauses" (or "...des Mehrfamilienhauses") which will be more practical probably. but in general it does not matter grammatically whether the sentence makes sense in the real world or not.

Comment: @LeonMeier Yes! You can definitely say "ich bin Käufer des..." - in your context however your example is more appropriate. It stresses that you're the only buyer and the definitive person to talk to.

Answer (score 0):

Du kannst entweder den unbestimmten Artikel verwenden

> [...] ich bin *ein* Käufer des Fahrrades Nr. 123. [...]

oder noch besser ganz auf einen Artikel verzichten

> [...] ich bin Käufer des Fahrrades Nr. 123. [...]

Auch wenn es modern ist, sollte man Fragen nicht durch den Hinweis einleiten, dass man eine Frage hat. Besser auf das hinweisen, was du erreichen willst (Anliegen klarmachen, vielleicht hat ja der Händler einen besseren Vorschlag). Also lieber:

> [...] ich bin Käufer des Fahrrades Nr. 123. Ich möchte gerne XXX erreichen. Wie kann ich YYY?

Wenn du darauf nicht verzichten willst dann aber doch wenigstens auf den unpassenden Konjunktiv. Du *hast* ja schließlich eine Frage und es besteht nicht nur die Möglichkeit, dass du sie hast.

Comment: I see no need for the conjunctive: „Ich habe folgende Frage an Sie“. But why writing something that is obvious? I think it makes more sense to introduce thematic issues: „Ich habe Probleme mit der Schaltung meines Fahrrads 123, wie kann ich ...?“

Answer (score -1):

You *have* to specify if you are a group or an individual.

You can say:

> Wir sind der Käufer des Fahrrads 123.

or

> Ich bin der Käufer des Fahrrads 123.

but as Zac67 already mentioned, you can leave the article before Käufer out.

Comment: Warum _wir_? Das hat doch nichts mit der Fragestellung zu tun und klingt eher gestelzt. Der OP möchte es lediglich offenlassen, wieviele Käufer das Modell gekauft haben und nicht, ob einer oder mehrere _ein_ Fahrrad gekauft haben.